# verifying a combinatorial inequality

Tags: co.combinatorics

Math people:

I would like to verify a conjecture: letting $n \geq 2$, and letting $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n, \gamma_1, \gamma_2, \ldots, \gamma_n$ be distinct positive reals with $\gamma_1 < \gamma_2 < \cdots < \gamma_n$, $\vec{\mu} = [\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n]$ and $\vec{\gamma} = [\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n]$, my conjecture is

$$ f(\vec{\mu},\vec{\gamma})\equiv \sum_{\mathbf{v} \in \{-1,1\}^n} \prod_{i=2}^n \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (v_i \gamma_i -v_j \gamma_j) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n (\mu_i + v_j \gamma_j) \cdot 2^{\mathbf{v}\cdot \vec{\gamma}} >0.   $$

This problem is related to the one I posed at [looking for proof or partial proof of determinant conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137774/looking-for-proof-or-partial-proof-of-determinant-conjecture) , but I have transformed it, and perhaps someone new will be able to shed some light on it, now that it is in a different form.

The case $n=2$ has been solved, as has the case where all the $\mu$'s are greater than all the $\gamma$'s.  I have run a lot of experiments testing the conjecture in Maple, using fractions to avoid roundoff error, and the conjecture has held every single time.  I have not tested it, but I suspect the conjecture is also true if you allow the $\mu$'s to be zero or coincide with each other or the $\gamma$'s.

I have run many experiments generating $\vec{\mu}$ and $\vec{\gamma}$ randomly, and looking at $f(s\vec{\mu},\vec{\gamma})$, which is a polynomial of degree $n^2$ in $s$.  The coefficients of all the powers of $s$ have always been positive.  Thanks to an answer to my previous question, I am 99% sure that the coefficient of $s^{n^2}$ is positive.  Unfortunately, that still leaves $n^2 -1$ coefficients.  If there is some combinatorial way to show the coefficients of all the powers of $s$ in 
$f(s\vec{\mu},\vec{\gamma})$ are all positive, that would solve the problem.

This does not look like an easy problem, and I am not taking it for granted that someone will have a complete answer.

For a vector $\mathbf{w}$ of length $n$, does the quantity 
$\prod_{i=2}^n \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (w_i - w_j)$ have a name?  What is known about it?

Comment: The quantity $\prod_{i=2}^n \prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(w_i-w_j)$ looks like the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix.